# Unwanted comma in php output

Tags: php

I'm fighting a PHP thingy. My code outputs correctly buts leaves an unwanted comma at the end. Is there a way to not get (or display) the last comma? Any tip is appreciated.

```
<?php echo mtbxr_val('dog_name'); ?>
&nbsp;is&nbsp;
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'behaviour_options' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo mb_strtolower($term->name);
    echo ", ";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use arrays to gather the values and then echo with join(). Example:

```
<?php 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'behaviour_options' );
$names = array();
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $names[] = mb_strtolower($term->name);
}
echo join(', ', $names);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually I store in an array and use `implode()`:

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $output[] = mb_strtolower($term->name);
}
echo implode(', ', $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a much easier way to do it

```
<?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'behaviour_options' );
    $out = array();
    foreach ( $terms as &$term ) {
        $out[] = mb_strtolower($term->name);
    }

    echo implode(", ",$out);
?>
```

Comment: Except `$terms` is an array of objects, hence the loop and reference to `$term->name`.

Comment: I just saw that, my mistake.  Edited response

Answer (score 0):

Aside from implode, you could also use a counter:

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'behaviour_options' );
$termCount = count($terms);
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo mb_strtolower($term->name);
    if (--$termCount) echo ", ";
}
?>
```